# The weak pointer example in The C++ Programming Language

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Trying to understand the example for `weak_ptr` in Stroustrup's TCPL (pp 995, 4th Ed.). I understand the goal is to grab into a shared pointer (to a neighbor asteroid) when needed. The example code is:

```
void owner()
{
    //...
    vector<shared_ptr<Asteroid>> va(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); ++i) {
        va[i].reset(new Asteroid(weak_ptr<Asteroid>(va[neighbor])));  // why?
    }
}
```

A lot of stuff is going on in the marked line. I don't understand why `reset` is used,  and why the constructor accepts a `weak_ptr`? Can someone explain that line in more details?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-weak_ptr) help?

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the earmarked line,- `Asteroid()` constructor will accept a `weak_ptr` as a parameter and returns a `shared_ptr`. `vector element va[i]` relinquished any earlier ownership by calling `reset` before accepting the new shared_ptr.

The simplified code will look like so: Every new Asteroid will have a pointer to another neighbouring Asteroid, this pointer should be a weak_ptr to avoid cyclic reference due to interconnecting Asteroid pointers.

```
vector<shared_ptr<Asteroid>> va(100);
for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); ++i)
{
    shared_ptr<Asteroid>sp = va[neighbor];
    weak_ptr<Asteroid> wp = sp;
    shared_ptr<Asteroid>sp2 = make_shared<Asteroid>(wp);
    va[i].reset(sp2);
}
```

Comment: The cyclic reference issue is a distraction. Real issue: "_Each asteroid must keep a list of other asteroids in its neighborhood. Note that being on such a neighbor list should not keep an astroid "alive" (so a shared_ptr would be inappropriate)._" http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-weak_ptr

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` fuction is equivalent to the assign operator (=), the difference is that the assign operator adds the shared_ptr object as a shared owner of the Asteroid object's assets,  increasing their use_count, while the `reset()` function makes the `shared_ptr` acquires ownership of p with a use count of 1, making all the other owners release their ownership.

So, in this code, `reset` is being used to make `va[i]` the unique owner of the object at the time.